# search patten between xml tags and replace parts of it

Tags: xml, regex, awk, sed

im trying to replace a string between the following tags
**orig:**

```
...<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">some text hmtl encoded and multiline
e.g <br /><strong>title:</strong></Data>.. ..next
element.....<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">some text hmtl encoded and
multiline e.g <br /><strong>title2:</strong></Data>..
```

**output:**

```
...<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">some text hmtl encoded and multiline
e.g &amp;lt;br /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;title:&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;</Data>.. ..next
element.....<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">some text hmtl encoded and
multiline e.g &amp;lt;br /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;title2:&amp;lt;/strong></Data>..
```

i have to seach for all elements with "`<`" or "`>`" and replace them with "`&amp;lt;`" or "`&amp;gt;`", but only if these are between "`<Data ss:Type="String">`" and "`</Data>`". the pattern must include multiline search.
"`<Data..`" is not at the start of the line and "`</Data>`" is not at the end of the line
The Type is usually string but it can be another type.

i tried with

```
awk '/<Data>.*<\/Data>/{sub("<","&amp;lt;",$0)} 1' $sourcefile |
awk '/<Data>.*<\/Data>/{sub(">","&amp;gt;",$0)} 1' >$outputfile
```

but it don't find / replace it in the correct way.

have someone an idea how to solve it?
thx!

Comment: You need a dual regex to do this. One to grab the contents, one to replace the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="<Data"} NR==1{print} NR>1{x=match($0,/>/);y=match($0,/<\/Data/);s=substr($0,x+1,y-x-1); gsub(/</,"\&amp;lt;",s);gsub(/>/,"\&amp;gt;",s);print RS substr($0,0,x) s substr($0,y)}' file
```

OUTPUT:

```
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">some text hmtl encoded and multiline
e.g &amp;lt;br /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;title:&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;</Data>.. ..next
element.....<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">some text hmtl encoded and
multiline e.g &amp;lt;br /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;title2:&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;</Data>
```

If you don't want newlines then set `ORS=""` in `BEGIN`

Comment: thx @WYSIWYG! instead of replacing with something i would need to search this part of the string (substring) and replace the `<` and `>` with `&amp;lt;` or `&amp;gt;`

Comment: hi, the command is perfect thx!! i extended it with the following command `sed -e 's/<amp;lt/amp;lt/g' |
sed -e 's/>amp;gt/amp;gt/g' >$outputfile` thx!

Comment: But it is not necessary, I guess, because there are no patterns like `>amp;gt`. Anyways you can combine the two sed commands- just put a `;` between the two statements